# Remove directory on dynamic links with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I wrote the following codes with .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^articles/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)$ page.php?article_seolink=$1 [NC,NE,L]
```

And I created the following URL address

> example.com/articles/article-title

But I want to create a link like

> example.com/article-title

How can I do this and redirect old URL to new one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following rules. Please make sure to place your htaccess Rules file inside articles folder. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)$ page.php?article_seolink=$1 [NC,NE,L]
```